# java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.collect.Iterators.emptyIterator()

Tags: hive

I'm using hadoop 3.2.1 and hive 2.3.6.
When I run show databases, it shows the following error

```
'''
hive> show databases;
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.collect.Iterators.emptyIterator()Lcom/google/common/collect/UnmodifiableIterator; from class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.<init>(FetchOperator.java:108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchTask.initialize(FetchTask.java:87)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:541)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1317)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1457)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:233)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:184)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:403)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:821)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:759)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:686)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
'''
```

What does it mean?And why do i get this error? Please give clarity.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

According to the release page [1] Hive 2.3.3 works with Hadoop 2.x.y (not 3.x.y) so if you want to run with Hadoop 3.2.1 try a newer version.

Other than that the error looks like a classpath problem related with guava. I guess you have one Guava version coming from Hive and another version coming from Hadoop. Try removing one of them. For instance:

```
cd apache-hive-2.3.3-bin/lib
rm guava*
```

Even if you solve the problem above most likely you will bump up into another so it is better to choose versions that are compatible.

[1] https://hive.apache.org/downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade to apache-hive-3.1.2 if that is an option for you. I had exact same issue that was resolved by the upgrade. Other option may be would be to compare lib folder of hive 2.3.6 versus hive 3.1.2; this issue is primarily due to incompatible jars.